# ImportError raised when running python -m

Tags: python, python-2.7, importerror

Given the following directory tree:

```
program.py
|--__init__.py
|--directory
   |--_init__.py
   |--a.py
   |--framework
      |--__init__.py
      |--b.py
   |--tests
      |--__init__.py
      |--a_test.py
      |--b_test.py
```

Each test imports the module its testing with the following syntax: 'from directory import module'. In addition a.py imports b.py using the same syntax

When the following commands are run from '/program' a_test fails with an ImportError on a importing b into a:
python -m directory/tests/a_test

However, when b_test is run with the same command, it works fine!

How do I get this to work correctly?

Comment: will you please provide traceback for the exception ?

Comment: Sounds like a circular import problem. Without seeing the imports or traceback it is impossible to tell, however.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/katie/story/story/python/tests/paragraph_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from story.python import paragraph
  File "story/python/paragraph.py", line 1, in <module>
    from story.python.framework import collector
ImportError: No module named python.framework`

Comment: @KAtkinson The traceback should be append to the problem description, not in the comments.